# Apache AliasMatch Variable Redirect Loop

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, vhosts, mod-alias

I'm trying to set up apache with an alias with and rewrite rules.

I have rewrite set up to forward all requests to index.php. That works great.

My issue is with setting up the AliasMatch for some specific locations.

If the client browses to `/core/plugins/<plugin_name>/client`, I want the alias to map the directory to `/var/www/example.com/src/plugins/<plugin_name>/client` on the server

The plugin name is variable and may or may not exist.

Here is my apache vhost config:

```
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/src/public

AliasMatch ^/core/plugins/(.+)/client /var/www/example.com/src/plugins/$1/client

<Directory /var/www/example.com/src/public>
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT]
    RewriteBase /
</Directory>
```

When I browse to `/core/plugins/plugin1/client/style.css`, the file served should theoretically be `/var/www/example.com/src/plugins/plugin1/client/style.css`, but instead I just get a redirect loop that adds `/index.html` repeatedly until my browser hangs for too many redirects. I'm not even referencing `index.html` in my config.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood use of `Alias` and `AliasMatch` here. Target of both directives is an **existing** filesystem path outside `DocumentRoot`

Comment: the target SHOULd exist, but may not. If that's the case the rewrite rule should take over and just serve index.php. What I meant by may or may not exists, is I cannot account for plugin names in the apache config, but I can account for where they will be.

Comment: Your rewrite rules will only work for the `DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/src/public` not for the paths outside `DocumentRoot`

Comment: The alias should add it though so the rewrite engine sees it as in the document, no? My alias works as I want it if I hard code a plugin name, but what I want is to use a variable in the alias path to account for whatever plugin name is given.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by using the following AliasMatch rule:

```
AliasMatch "^/core/plugins/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/(.*)" "/var/www/example.com/src/plugins/$1/client/$2/$3"
```

An explanation of what this is doing in my case -

The user inputs: `/core/plugins/plugin1/css/style.css`

The first argument of the Alias rule, `"^/core/plugins/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/(.*)"`, checks the user input and assigns `$1` to the output of `([^\/]+)` which is `plugin1` in this case, `$2` to the output of `([^\/]+)` which is `css` in this case, and `$3` to `(.*)` which is everything left in the url after `$2/`, `style.css` in this case. These variables `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` can be used to map the path in the second argument. In my case `"/var/www/example.com/src/plugins/$1/client/$2/$3"`

Think of the regex output as `/core/plugins/$1/$2/$3` with reference to the second argument.

So, based on the user input `/core/plugins/plugin1/css/style.css`, the actual file mapped will be `/var/www/example.com/src/plugins/plugin1/client/css/style.css`

I hope this helps people that are running into this issue.